# How to serialize form inputs in a .change event with javascript/PHP/CURL?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm working on a small project that requires Ajax to fetch data from database and update a page. The query to the database is built on the fly by the user and the query strings build like a chain. So for example the first item of the chain effects the next and the next and so on. Therefore it creates a list of post variables that I can't "know" ahead of time. I figured this would be a pretty simple thing to achieve however it's proving not to be. Here is my issue.

When I use a .changed event and try to seralize the form before posting it. I get nothing but empty strings. I've noticed that if I hard code the post variables everything works just fine. Is there something I'm missing? Does .changed not have a seralize method?

I am also using a CURL bridge since the server with the data is on another domain. I don't think that is causing any issues though. I believe it has to do with my event choice.

Here is the code:

```
    $('#selector').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/pages/curlbridge.php",
            data: $("#queryform").serialize(), //"select=all&date=2013"
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                var resultset = data;

            }
        });
```

Was Asked to attach the HTML. It's just a simple form

```
    <form id="selector">
        Select: <input type="text" id="select" />
        Date: <input type="text" id="date" />
    </form>
    <br />
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this should work, what does `console.log($("#queryform").serialize());` show you before the ajax call and what is missing in that string, only values or also key-value pairs?

Comment: POST http://intranetserver/pages/curlbridge.php
 
200 OK
  35ms 
jquery.min.js (line 4)
HeadersPostHTMLCookies

null



It just shows "null" in firebug when I check the console. Status 200, null for the post and (empty string) for the response from the server because I sent it nothing.

Comment: Could you attach the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#queryform") does not exist. Your jQuery should read like this:

```
$('#selector').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/pages/curlbridge.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(), //"select=all&date=2013"
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            var resultset = data;

        }
    });
});
```

Also, are you using .change() because you want to submit the AJAX request every time a user enters a key?

Comment: This worked :D.. It was my mistake to use the name of the element. As for the change event this was just a test, when it's all done I will probably use a input select rather then leaving it as an open field. 

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @m1ket that #queryform doesn't exist, although you can't use serialize() on a single input element, so the following line is incorrect:

```
    data: $(this).serialize(), //"select=all&date=2013"
```

Perhaps what you can do is this (which gets all the data in the form the #selector is a part of):

```
    data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(), //"select=all&date=2013"
```

**EDIT**

My bad, I didn't pay attention to the HTML posted in the original question

Scope issue maybe? Does this work:

```
$('#selector').change(function() {
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/pages/curlbridge.php",
        data: formData, //"select=all&date=2013"
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            var resultset = data;

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: $('#selector') is a form though. So surely $(this).serialize() would work?

Comment: Voted up because it's basically the same as the other answer these both work